# Circle and Trigonometry Problem

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[image]

We have a unit circle and we know that $m(PBA)=\alpha.$

If the ordinate of the $P$ point is $\cos(7\alpha)$ what is the degree of $\alpha$?

Comment: Coordinates in two dimensions are written in the form $(x,y)$. Which coordinate of $P$ are you referring to?

Comment: @mrnovice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate

Comment: This $P(t,cos(7α))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P_y=\cos7\alpha$ and, by definition of the sine function, 
$P_y=\sin POA=\sin2\alpha$, we have the equation
$$
\cos7\alpha = \sin2\alpha.
$$
Solving this equation with the additional condition $$0<\alpha\le45^\circ$$ we find $\alpha=10^\circ$. (We used the fact that $\sin x=\cos(90^\circ-x)$, hence $2\alpha = 90^\circ - 7\alpha$.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint...since the angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference, the angle POA is $2\alpha$ so you need to solve the equation $$\cos7\alpha=\sin2\alpha=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\alpha)...$$